# How do I import .csv file in Watson studio[IBM cloud] from desktop?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I import a csv file in the dashboard.
[image]

Then I clicked on 'Insert Pandas DataFRames'. Then the following command was added in the jupyter notebook[image]

Then I executed the commads. I got the error message.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use read_csv() and pass body as the argument to read the data into dataframe.

```
 df_data_0 = pd.read_csv(body)
 df_data_0.head()
```

Then use .head() to print the dataframe top rows.